# WebStorm Flow integration - false positive with React and Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, webstorm, flowtype

I have a component with declared props:
[image]

And I'm using it in another place:
[image]

`ModalWindow` component is connected by react-redux and gets its props from store that's why this shouldn't be reported by WebStorm (flow doesn't complain).

**P.S.** Actually there is another issue with not providing `history` prop neither by `withRoute` or `connect` in place of component definition and flow is quiet about that. But that unfortunately different story...

Can I somehow tell WebStorm that this props are indeed provided?

The way I make it disappear is to declare:

```
ModalWindow.propTypes = {
  //they can be even empty!
};
```